# Matching with Rc<RefCell<T>>

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, ownership

Consider the following code - which compiles and works:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use crate::Foo::{Something, Nothing};

enum Foo {
    Nothing,
    Something(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let wrapped = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Foo::Nothing));
    //....

    match *wrapped.borrow() {
        Something(x) => println!("{}", x),
        Nothing => println!("Nothing"),
    };        
}
```

Now I want to match two wrapped values instead of just one:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use crate::Foo::{Something, Nothing};

enum Foo {
    Nothing,
    Something(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let wrapped1 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Foo::Nothing));
    let wrapped2 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Foo::Nothing));
    //....

    match (*wrapped1.borrow(), *wrapped2.borrow()) {
        (Something(x), Something(y)) => println!("{}, {}", x, y),
        _ => println!("Nothing"),
    };        
}
```

Now this will give the compile error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of `std::cell::Ref<'_, Foo>`
  --> src\main.rs:16:12
   |
16 |     match (*wrapped1.borrow(), *wrapped2.borrow()) {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Foo`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of `std::cell::Ref<'_, Foo>`
  --> src\main.rs:16:32
   |
16 |     match (*wrapped1.borrow(), *wrapped2.borrow()) {
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Foo`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I do not quite understand the fundamental difference between the semantics of the two examples. Why is it happening and what would be the correct way of making the second snippet work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```rust
    match (*wrapped1.borrow(), *wrapped2.borrow()) {
```

You created a tuple here on the spot. And the values were being moved into the newly created tuple. This works though:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use crate::Foo::Something;

enum Foo {
    Nothing,
    Something(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let wrapped1 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Foo::Nothing));
    let wrapped2 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Foo::Nothing));

    match (&*wrapped1.borrow(), &*wrapped2.borrow()) {
        (Something(x), Something(y)) => println!("{}, {}", x, y),
        _ => println!("Nothing"),
    };        
}
```

Comment: wow ok it all clicks now thanks to this answer and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66494730/34871 . So: borrow returns an immutable lock-guard `Ref<T>`, which can panic if any mutable borrow exists, and will make a mutable borrow panic if not yet dropped ; `*` dereferences to `T`, but does not move out yet, because we immediately take a reference with `&`. With this `&*x.borrow()` syntax, the `Ref<T>` just exists for the scope of the match, so it's safe to take a mutable reference later on after the `match` ( Holding the `Ref` in a variable would require an explicit drop )