# Immutable reference to data in RefCell

Tags: vector, indexing, rust, immutability, refcell

I'm trying to implement the Index method for a struct with interior mutability:

```
pub struct FooVec {
    foo: RefCell<Vec<i32>>
}

impl Index<usize> for FooVec {
    type Output = i32;

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        self.foo.borrow().index(index)
    }
}
```

However, this does not compile due to:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
 --> src\lacc\expr.rs:9:9
  |
9 |         self.foo.borrow().index(index)
  |         -----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |         |
  |         returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
  |         temporary value created here
```

My solution would be to return a reference of the vector in the RefCell. But the only method I find
which does that is get_mut() and for the Index trait I need to return an immutable reference...

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to deal with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't implement `Index`: the `Index` trait requires returning a reference, this means that it has to return something which is attached to and *trivially* accessible from the object.

That's not the case here as you need to go through `RefCell::borrow`, which essentially functions as if it were creating a value from scratch (because it only hands out access through [a Ref "lock guard"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Ref.html)).

> I would appreciate any suggestions on how to deal with this.

Do something else. `Index` is not an option. Given the types involved I'd suggest just implementing a `get` method which returns an `Option<i32>`, something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. I don't understand why RefCell implements get_mut() and not get() though..

Comment: @Adam because that could not uphold Rust's aliasing guarantees: `get_mut()` requires a mutable reference, so we statically know there's only one reference to the `RefCell` and nobody has any way to get an other one concurrently through `borrow` or `borrow_mut`. However since `get()` would only require an immutable reference, we could concurrently call `borrow_mut()`, and the `RefCell` would have no way to know that there are outstanding references, therefore we'd concurrently have a mutable reference and a non-zero number of immutable references, which is absolutely verboten.

Comment: Also you may want to take a look at owning-ref, it's rather complicated to use but the point is to carry references and their owners together, so that might work out for you.